# if the order is lack of property of reflexive,can it be total order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> X on {a}* so that eVf iff length(e) smaller than length(f)
>
> i noticed that the order is lack of (Λ,Λ) (a,a),so it is not reflexive and not the total order.but the ans told that is the total order.can someone explain?

Comment: Maybe they meant to say $\leq$  instead of $<$.

Comment: so if the symbol is <,the ans is not total order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A total order is a strict order in most definitions, but I'll state definitions that are commonly used:

A partial order is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. We can call it total if $\forall x,y \in X: (x \le y \lor y \le x)$ holds.

Your definition (though somewhat unclearly written) as $x \le y$ iff $\operatorname{len}(x) \le_{\mathbb{N}} \operatorname{len}(y)$ is a linear order on $X=\{a\}^\ast$. If we define $x R y$ iff $\operatorname{len}(x) <_{\mathbb{N}} \operatorname{len}(y)$, we don't have a partial order (so not a total partial order) but a (strict) total order that usually obeys the axioms (denoting it by the symbol $R$ here):

- $\forall x: \lnot xRx$
- $\forall x,y: x \neq y \implies x R y \lor y R x$
- $\forall x,y,z: x R y \land yRz \implies xRz$

and it's easy to check that $<$ is defined does obey these.